# Integral of $\frac{1+2z}{1+z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $C$ be a curve in the upper half plane with initial point $-1+2i$ and final point $1+2i$.

Let $f(z) = \frac{1+2z}{1+z}dz$

I need to find the integral of $f$ over $C$.

If I take $C(t) = (1-2t) + 2i$ for $t \in [0,1]$ then I am getting some value for the integral.

But how do I prove that the integral is path independent?

Comment: What do you know about sufficient conditions for path independence of contour integrals?

Comment: If I show that integral of f over any closed curve is zero or if I show that f has a primitive, then the integral will be path independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral is path-independent because the upper half-plane is simply connected and the integral of any analytic function defined on a simply connected set along a path $\gamma$ only depends upon the initial and final points of $\gamma$.

Comment: It isn't analytic at -1, right?

Comment: What if C encloses -1?

Comment: Then f won't be analytic on C..Right?

Comment: It's *undefined* at $1$ (and therefore neither it is nor it isn't analytic there). But $-1$ does not belong to the upper half-plane.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to wait until I answer a question posted in a comment before posting another question in another comment?

Comment: That was the extension of the same question.

Comment: Is my answer to your question clear?

Comment: Yes. It is. Thanks

Comment: Even easier in this case, you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  This function has a primitive which can be computer explicitly.